# CodeIgniter email mail error

Tags: codeigniter

I'm getting this error with the `mail()` function in CodeIgniter:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: mail() [function.mail]: Bad parameters to mail() function, mail not sent.

Filename: libraries/Email.php

Line Number: 1519
```

Here is my mail script (part of my controller):

```
$message = "...text...";
$this->load->library('email');
$this->email->from('oemsales@xxx.com', 'OEM Sales');
$this->email->to('xxxx@xxx.com');
$this->email->subject('Contact Page Request');
$this->email->message($message);
$this->email->send();
```

Line 1519 is the line where the email is sent.  What is going on here?

SOLVED:  Found the answer here: http://codeignitertips.blogspot.com/.  It was a GoDaddy issue.

Comment: A solution for this problem for this problem can also be found here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350865/malformed-email-subject-header-when-subject-75-chars-using-codeigniter-email-l/30919390#30919390

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the correct email address in your `to` method. Make sure of it.