# malformed email subject header when subject > 75 chars using codeigniter email lib

Tags: email, codeigniter, utf-8, mime

I'm getting some garble in my MIME headers when the subject is over 75 chars.
When the line break is encoded in the header there is an extra line break that is invalid.

Some email gateways are bouncing the email with a **"Malformed MIME field: ?= =?utf-8?Q?SUBJECT?="** error.

Does anyone have any experience with utf-8 problems sending emails with CodeIgniter?

---

```
-snip-
Return-Path: ***
Subject: =?utf-8?Q?SUBJECT_LINE    <--
?=                                 <-- Problem in Subject header
 =?utf-8?Q?SUBECT_LINE_2?=         <--
To: ***
Reply-To: ***
-snip-
```

---

**Update:**
This has nothing to do with gmail smtp. I have rewritten the question in the hope that it will help someone out in the future.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently this is a known issue, caused by Subject lines > 75 chars.

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/154493/P15/#925385

The fix was to change the email config like this:

```
$config['newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['crlf']    = "\n";
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I used the in-line config strings, though: `$this->email->newline = "\r\n";` and `$this->email->crlf = "\n";`

Comment: I like putting it in its own config file, but they both work. You can also create a separate instance of the email object with its own separate config parameters: `$email = new CI_Email(array('newline' => "\r\n"));`

Comment: There is also a problem with CodeIgniter putting the newlines in the middle of multi-byte chars. Look at https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1498

Comment: haha, i am working on some legacy system, i was not known to me >75 issue, and thanks for answer

Answer (score 5):

Since I myself had this exact problem I will share the solution here since the one shared does not work with version 2.2

Find this piece of code located in **system/libraries/Email.php:365**

```
public function subject($subject)
{
    $subject = $this->_prep_q_encoding($subject);
    $this->_set_header('Subject', $subject);
    return $this;
}
```

With this one

```
public function subject($subject)
{
    $subject = '=?UTF-8?B?'.base64_encode($subject).'?=';
    $this->_set_header('Subject', $subject);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: oh god I think I love you - i have spent 4 hours banging my head, wish i could give you 10 upvotes!!!