# CodeIgniter weird emails being sent

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, html-email

I have a function that I can pass parameters to easily send emails.

This is it :

```
function __construct() {
        $this -> CI = get_instance();
        $this -> CI -> load -> library('email');
    }

    public function send_one_email($single_email, $single_subject, $single_body, $single_attach) {
        $this -> CI -> email -> clear();
        $this -> CI -> email -> to($single_email);
        $this -> CI -> email -> from('**************');
        $this -> CI -> email -> subject($single_subject);
        $this -> CI -> email -> message($single_body);

        if ($single_attach) {
            $this -> CI -> email -> attachment($single_attach);
        }

        if ($this -> CI -> email -> send()) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
```

The emails I am receiving are (which I should not be receiving) :

> ?=  =?utf-8?Q?2013?= Reply-To: "SUNYOrangeScholarInterface@gmail.com"
>    X-Sender:
>   SUNYOrangeScholarInterface@gmail.com X-Mailer: CodeIgniter X-Priority:
>   3 (Normal) Message-ID: <520eb8d943533@gmail.com> Mime-Version: 1.0
>   Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_520eb8d943598"
>
> This is a multi-part message in MIME format. Your email application
>   may not support this format.
>
> --B_ALT_520eb8d943598 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
>
> Hello Rixhers Ajazi this is an automated email to notify you that your
>   account has been successfully created.You must wait for your account
>   to be verified meaning that you do not have access to use
>   ScholarInterface. Once your account is activated and you are given a
>   user role you will be notified via email.Please be advised that since
>   you have created your account you are responsible for keeping your
>   credentials safe. These include your email account, your answers to
>   your security questions, and your password itself.I (Rixhers Ajazi)
>   just want to warn you that if you do not keep your security answers
>   safe then some one can take over your account.Any questions what so
>   ever with ScholarInterface please email Rixhers Ajazi at
>   CoderRix@gmail.comAny questions pertaining to your account please
>   notify your Administrators. Rixhers Ajazi is not a Administrator but a
>   Super User (the coder of this program).
>
> --B_ALT_520eb8d943598 Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
>
> Hello Rixhers Ajazi this is an automated email to notify you that your
>   acco= unt has been successfully created.You must wait for your account
>   to be veri= fied meaning that you do not have access to use
>   **ScholarInterface**. On= ce your account is activated and you are
>   given a user role you will be noti= fied via email.Please be advised
>   that since you have created your account y= ou are responsible for
>   keeping your credentials safe. These include your em= ail account,
>   your answers to your security questions, and your password its= elf.I
>   (Rixhers Ajazi) just want to warn you that if you do not keep your se=
>   curity answers safe then some one can take over your account.Any
>   questions = what so ever with **ScholarInterface** please email
>   Rixhers Ajazi at Cod= erRix@gmail.comAny questions pertaining to your
>   account please notify your = Administrators. Rixhers Ajazi is not a
>   Administrator but a Super User (the = coder of this program).
>
> --B_ALT_520eb8d943598--

The hell is this?

This is my configuration in email.php :

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

 $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
 $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com';
 $config['smtp_user'] = '********************@gmail.com';
 $config['smtp_pass'] = '**************************';
 $config['smtp_port'] = 465;
 $config['smtp_timeout'] = 30;
 $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
 $config['crlf'] = "\r\n";
 $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
 $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
 $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
```

I use the same script with another application and I haven't ever gotten this. Any help would be great.

Comment: You say you have used the same script with another application... Is the server environment different? Any accompanying errors in your logs?

Comment: The message seems to start from the subject header, so I would guess it's a problem with the length of your subject. Try submitting the email again with a short subject < 75 characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The message at the top of the email seems to start from the subject header, so I would guess that would be a good place to start debugging.

There used to be an [issue caused by Subject lines with more than 75 chars](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/154493/P15/#925385).

If the above fix doesn't work, then the devs have patched the Email.php to solve the problem:

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/issues/1409#issuecomment-9330713

Comment: Thanks a lot! This answer pointed me in the right direction to this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350865/malformed-email-subject-header-when-subject-75-chars-using-codeigniter-email-l

Comment: So far I haven't gotten any malformed emails yet.

Comment: thank you for the link and the answer, worked like a charm once i shortened my sublect

Answer (score 0):

```
Just add this in start of the function where you are writing send email code 
$config = Array(
          'protocol' => 'sendmail',
          'mailtype' => 'html', 
          'charset' => 'utf-8',
          'wordwrap' => TRUE

      );
     $this->email->initialize($config);
Email will forward but error same error will show
```